# How to integrate third party API in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have created a Shopify store and now I want to send orders to the third party e-commerce website. I have third party API but I don't know how to integrate it in my Shopify store. Could anyone explain to me the steps to make an app to integrate third party API?

PS: I am new to Shopify

Answer (score 7):

Here is a recipe you can follow based on experience. I have done this 20+ times and I can tell you you are looking at about 5-10 hours of work to get it done.

- open up a Shopify Partner account
- login as a partner and navigate to Apps
- create an App and set it to run at your favourite cloud provider
- install the App in your shop
- add an endpoint in your App to accept Shopify webhooks
- parse the webhook data when it arrives so you can send that data to your 3rd party API
- add the code to contact your 3rd party API and send them the data

That is all there is to it. Standard web/internet computing with a bit of oAuth token exchange with Shopify, a simple web App on your part, and the connection to a service for data exchange.

Comment: Thank you David, Do you have a tutorial link for this?

Comment: Shopify has a decent collection of articles: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides and their Github repository is a rich source of demos and code that works.

Comment: Hey, David. I am working on a web project and related to Shopify API.
Shopify api telling me about 7k orders(orders/count.json). but there are 170k orders actually.

how can i get all orders through the API?

Comment: @DavidLazar i have been asked to help create an api to hook into a shopify store and have a few dumb questions I can't seem to find on their resources would you be willing to answer them?

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can use a Shopify webhooks functionality

```
Go to admin = >settings =>Notifications
```

than in the bottom you will see a

```
create webhook option
```

`click on create webhook` and `select event from dropdwon`  and

```
specify the path of your api where you want the shopify order data.

It will send all the data to your api whenever your order will be placed/update.
```

Hope ths will help.

here is the reference  https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks
Thnaks

Comment: But how to set API there? I am getting only URL option

Comment: hi you must have written your api somewhere. You just need to put the url of your api in the webhook section and  make of log of requests in that so you  can know what data shopify has sent y=to you.

Comment: I haven't written an API anywhere. Where am I supposed to write 3rd party API?

Comment: than how you want to sync data to another websites f there is no api?

Comment: Please go to orders ->GET in this URL https://api.picanova.com/docs ...Do I have to add https://api.picanova.com/api/beta/orders in webhook URL in Shopify?